# Ways to make change

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Given unlimited coins with values $1^2$, $2^2$, $3^2$, $4^2$,..., $17^2$
Now given an amount X, in how many ways can we exchange it using these coins?

Example for $X=24$ answer is $16$. It means there are 16 ways in which can use above coins to make a change of 24.

I need to find it for given X.

Comment: I don't think a closed formula is known

Answer (score 1):

Here is a c++ code for computing it:

```
#include <cstdio>
long long k[1000000];
long long main(){
  int a,b,c;
  k[0]=1;
  scanf("%lld",&a);
  for(b=1;b*b<2*a && b<18;b++){
    for(c=b*b;c<2*a;c++){
      k[c]=k[c]+k[c-b*b];
    }
  }
  printf("%lld\n",k[a]);
}
```

Here are the results for some evalues of $n$

$n=1: 1$

$n=2: 1$

$n=3: 1$

$n=4: 2$

$n=5: 2$

$n=6: 2$

$n=7: 2$

$n=8: 3$

$n=9: 4$

$n=10: 4$

$n=100: 1116$

$n=1000: 3734690646$

Comment: I think your program is considering values beyond 17^2 too. For n=1000, I get 3734690646

Comment: Oh, it's only up to 17^2?

Comment: Oh, I changed the code.

Comment: One small change required: b<18

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

An asymptotic formula may be possible, but a closed form looks difficult.

A generating function may be written as

\begin{align*}
G(x) &= \dfrac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{17} \left(1-x^{i^2}\right)}
\end{align*}

So, e.g. 
\begin{align*}
[x^{24}]G(x) &= 16\\
[x^{1000}]G(x) &= 3734690646\\
[x^{2000}]G(x) &= 6037511618509
\end{align*}
etc.

Comment: How did you use the generating function to get the terms?

Comment: Used a CAS -- after taylor expansion, the coefficients are the required series